# Show that map $p$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

We have $Y \subset C[0,1]$ be the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ which are polynomials of degree $\leq 2$, i.e. $ax^2+bx+c$.

Consider map $p:\mathbb{R}^3_\text{usual} \to Y$ mapping $(a,b,c)$ to $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$

Now we want to show that the maps $p:\mathbb{R}^3_\text{usual} \to Y_{L_1}$ and $p:\mathbb{R}^3_\text{usual} \to Y_{L_\infty}$ are continuous. (Here, $Y_{L_1}$ is the  under the $L_1$ topology.)

I tried doing $p^{-1}(B(f,\epsilon)) = \{ (a,b,c):\int_0^1 \lvert f(t) - at^2-bt-c \rvert < \epsilon \}$ but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $p$ is a linear map, so it suffices to show $p$ is bounded under the two norms. That is, we need to find constants $K_1$ and $K_\infty$ such that
\begin{align*}
\|p(a, b, c)\|_1 &\le K_1\|(a, b, c)\| \\
\|p(a, b, c)\|_\infty &\le K_\infty\|(a, b, c)\|.
\end{align*}
We have,
$$\|p(a, b, c)\|_1 = \int_0^1 |ax^2 + bx + c| \, \mathrm{d}x \le \int_0^1 |a|x^2 + |b|x + |c| \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{|a|}{3} + \frac{|b|}{2} + |c|.$$
Since $|a|, |b|, |c| \le \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$, we have
$$\|p(a, b, c)\|_1 \le \frac{\|(a, b, c)\|}{3} + \frac{\|(a, b, c)\|}{2} + \|(a, b, c)\| = \frac{11}{6}\|(a, b, c)\|,$$
so we may choose $K_1 = \frac{11}{6}$, i.e. $p$ is continuous as a map to $Y$ under the $L^1$ norm.

I'll let you think about the $L^\infty$ norm. Let me know if you need more help.